# SQLite Database, Table is created but values are not inserted into the Table

Tags: android, sqlite

i am trying to do the SQLite database example in that the table is created successfully but the valued are not inserted. please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String TAG = "MainActivity";
public DatabaseHelperAdapter dbHelper;
protected static final String String = null;
private Button save, cancel;
EditText fname, lname;

public static String FirstName = "";
public static String LastName = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

    fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_fname);
    lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_lname);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelperAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    dbHelper.open();

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dbHelper.addValues(FirstName, LastName);

        }
    });

}
```

DatabaseHelperAdapter

```
public class DatabaseHelperAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
public static final String Id = "_id";
public static final String FIRSTNAME = "first_name";
public static final String LASTNAME = "last_name";

private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private Context contex;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Aadhaar";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Enrollment";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;


private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table Enrollment (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "first_name text not null, last_name text not null);";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Regist");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DatabaseHelperAdapter(Context contex) {
    super();
    this.contex = contex;
}

public DatabaseHelperAdapter open() throws SQLException {

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(contex);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public long addValues(String fname, String lname) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put(FIRSTNAME, fname);
    initialValues.put(LASTNAME, lname);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}
}
```

In that if I enter value manually through SQLite editor then values are successfully added.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? warning ? Or anything ? Check this example : http://androiddevelopmentworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-sqlite-tutorial.html

Comment: did u added necessary permission in manifest.xml?

Comment: no, they did not giving any kind of error or warning.

Comment: no, i have not added any kind of permission in the manifest.xml.

Comment: u are placing db file in assert folder and accessing it?

Comment: sorry sir, but i did not get you. please be clear.

Comment: i am not placing any db file in assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       public void addValues(String fname, String Sname){
       //Get a writeable database
       SQLiteDatabase  db = getWritableDatabase();
        //Add your values to the contentValues
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Fname, fname);
        values.put(Sname,sname);

        //the table name is the name of your table
        //Insert the information in the contentValues values
        db.insert(table_name, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a object of your Database class of Sqlite in onClickmethod of button

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         dbHelper = new DatabaseHelperAdapter(MainActivity.this);
         dbHelper.open();
         dbHelper.addValues(FirstName, LastName);
         dbHelper.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: i have made the changes but the same problem is there..it shows the first column as a id but it shows the two column is blank..

Comment: Are you using external sqlite.db file or own self created??

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String TAG = "MainActivity";
public DatabaseHelperAdapter dbHelper;
protected static final String String = null;
private Button save, cancel;
EditText fname, lname;

public static String FirstName = "";
public static String LastName = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_fname);
lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_lname);

dbHelper = new DatabaseHelperAdapter(MainActivity.this);
dbHelper.open();

save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//You **Missed** these two lines of code..........

 FirstName=fname.getText().toString();
 LastName=lname.getText().toString();


        dbHelper.addValues(FirstName, LastName);

    }
});

}
```

Comment: Thank you... it works..thanks a lot...now i want to save that database in android device i have coded like this- ' DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, "/sdcard/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/" + DATABASE_NAME,
   null);
  
   }'

Comment: But the problem is, the SQLite database file is there at the sdcard but it will not get opened. So, how to open this file in android device?

Comment: move it to the assets folder in the project

Comment: No Acknowledgement for the answer?!